# Drawing on a SurfaceView

Tags: android

I've recently discovered the possibilities of the facerecognition api in android. I've seen that its not possible to draw a rectangle around a face, when its viewed live in a `SurfaceView`. But I have an idea, the `onFaceDetection` Listener has a `Face[]` as parameter. For each of these objects I can find the face's `Rect` like this:

```
for (android.hardware.Camera.Face f : faces) {
        Rect rect = f.rect;
        Log.d("Top: ", Integer.toString(rect.top));
        Log.d("Right: ", Integer.toString(rect.right));
        Log.d("Bottom: ", Integer.toString(rect.bottom));
        Log.d("Left: ", Integer.toString(rect.left));
}
```

By having all this, isn't it possible to add a `View` over the `SurfaceView` where this Rectangle can be drawn? If so, how can I draw a rectangle on the `SurfaceView` by using this information ?

Comment: Why can't you draw a rectangle around a face, when its viewed live in a SurfaceView? Can't you get a copy of that surfaceview instance?

Comment: What I meant, is that there is not methods for doing this. The preview of "what the camera sees" is displayed in the `surfaceView` defined in the layout xml. The questions is more, how can I draw a rectangle on a surfaceview ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, by putting the `SurfaceView` inside a `RelativeLayout`, and putting your rectangle `View` as a later child of that `RelativeLayout`. Later children are higher in the Z axis than earlier children and therefore will float over top of earlier children. However, that is "over", not "on". I do not know if you can successfully draw *on* the `SurfaceView` without your drawing getting obliterated by the pushed buffers from the camera preview.

Comment: Thanks for the input @CommonsWare. Doesnt really matter if I can draw on the `SurfaceView`, or over, as far as the user can see the rectangle on the screen.